# External CSS is not working in PHP

Tags: php, html

This is how I have used the link tag inside the Head tag. But it is not working. Please help me to solve this.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="ccc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title> 
</head>
```

Both the CSS and php files are in the same folder.

[image]

Comment: do you have `ccc.css` in the same folder as your PHP file is?

Comment: can you navigate to your `ccc.css` file via web browser???

Comment: check your `path file`.

Comment: are you sure its not working??? see details [tag_link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Comment: Yes both are in the same folder but still i am having the issue.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about CSS; the browser/client that renderes the document does. So, what is the browser (or its developer tools) actually complaining about?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1. If i run the CSS file in browser it shows like " HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server."

Comment: If i use the CSS codes internally its working. If i use externally my page is loading without CSS effects.

Comment: try this <link href="./ccc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: your file should be under apache  root directory

Comment: I am running PHP file using IIS configurations

Comment: Check your console in the browser, does it even register the CSS file as a needed resource and if so, what does the network console say? (ctrl+shift+j)